# Drawing a diagram showing how a parabola is generated

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, labeling

I need help. How do I create a  plot like the one shown below in Wolfram Mathematica?

It's the upper-right picture, for value of `p = 1/2`, that I want. Is it possible at all?

[image]

Comment: see [Wolfram Demonstrations  >> Constructing Quadratic Curves](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ConstructingQuadraticCurves/)

Answer (score 2):

```
ClearAll[f];
f[F_, y_] = x /. Solve[x^2 == (x - F)^2 + y^2, x][[1]]
Manipulate[
 Show[
  ParametricPlot[{f[F, y], y}, {y, -6, 6}],

  Graphics[{
    Point[{f[F, y], y}], Text["M", {f[F, y], y} + 0.25],
    Point[{F, 0}], Text["F", {F, 0} + 0.25],
    Point[{0, y}], Text["A", {0, y} + 0.25],
    Line[{{0, y}, {f[F, y], y}}],
    Line[{{F, 0}, {f[F, y], y}}]

    }],
  Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-6, 6}}, 
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
  ImageSize -> Large
  ],
 {{y, 1}, -6, 6}, {{F, 1}, -10, 10}
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Just for the giggles I fiddled this up: https://wolfr.am/AFSiGUta

Comment: Thank you! This rocks! :)

Comment: You're welcome! (I hope you've tried the sliders...)

Answer (score 1):

Just reverse your coordinates:

```
standardParabola[x_] := (x^2);
ListLinePlot[
 Table[Evaluate@{standardParabola[x], x}, {x, -5, 5, .01}]
 ]
```

[Try this online](https://wolfr.am/AFS6BGyB)

[image]

Comment: Tnx for help! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Plot[{Sqrt[x], -Sqrt[x]}, {x, -2, 4},
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Blue},
 Epilog -> {Green, Thickness[0.005], Line[{{-1, -2}, {-1, 2}}],
   Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[{1, 0}],
   Dashed, Line[{{1, 0}, {.25, .5}, {-1, .5}}]}]
```

[image]

I deliberately placed the locations of the points and lines incorrectly.  It is *your* job to get them right!

Comment: Thank you so much. It's more than enough. :)